# Auto check checkboxes by retriving their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I've met some issues by retrieving checkboxes from an array of values.

I tried to auto check the checkboxes which are concerned by an array.

array[i] generate some input of checkboxes
target[i] is an array which contains some checkboxe's values. So when I refresh the page, I have to see that "tuesday" and "Wendesday" is already selected. cf.the snippet
(I don't know if I explain correctly)

```js
// table which generate checkboxes
   
var array = new Array();
array[0]="Monday";
array[1]="Tuesday";
array[2]="Wendesday";
array[3]="Thirsday";
array[4]="Friday";
array[5]="Saturday";
array[6]="Sunday";

// values to of checkboxes I want to auto-check
var target = new Array();
target[0]="Tuesday";
target[1]="Wendesday";


var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
 j = i.toString();

 val = j;
 //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
 var cb = document.createElement('input');
 var label= document.createElement("label");

 cap = array[i];
 var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
 cb.type = 'checkbox';
 cbh.appendChild(cb);
 cb.name = cap;
 cb.value = val;
 label.appendChild(cb); 
 label.appendChild(text);
 cbh.appendChild(label);
}
```

```css
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
 padding:5px;
 width:100vw;
}
.multiselect {
 overflow: visible;
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 background-color:#eee;
 width:100vw;
 white-space: normal;
 height:50px;
}
.checkboxes {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
 display:inline-block;
}

label {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px grey solid;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
Tuesday and Wendesday have to be automitacly checked
```

Thank you for your help. 
Regards

Comment: *"So when I refresh the page..."* When you refresh the page, the entire thing is reloaded, starting from scratch. Your array will be gone. If you want this behavior, you will have to persist the array somewhere (`localStorage`, cookies, server-side, etc.) and then retrieve the array upon page load.

Comment: No, because when the page is relaoded, in the Javascript there is the array so it automaticly check the checkboxes concerned. I don't want to store it. When the user arrives, thoses two selections are already selected.

Comment: You are confusing "arriving" to the page with "refreshing" the page. When the page is refreshed, all content is gone and all of the code is reprocessed from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"So when I refresh the page..."* When you refresh the page, the entire thing is reloaded, starting from scratch. Your array will be gone. If you want this behavior, you will have to persist the array somewhere (`localStorage`, cookies, server-side, etc.) and then retrieve the array upon page load.

If that's not quite what you meant and you just want to have a static array, then you need to access that array and check the checkboxes upon page load.

You have quite a bit of unneeded code, so a corrected version looks like this:

```js
// Master array from which checkboxes are created (uses "array literal" syntax for shorter typing)
  var cbArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thirsday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

  // values to of checkboxes I want to auto-check
  var target = ["Tuesday", "Wendesday"];

  // Get element that will contain checkboxes
  var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
  const checkboxGroupName = "chkDays";  // It is common to give all checkboxes in a group the same name

  // Loop through the master array and make labels and checkboxes based on what's in it
   cbArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
 
    // Create and configure checkbox
   var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.value = item;
    cb.name = checkboxGroupName;
    cb.id = checkboxGroupName + (index + 1);
    
    // If new checkbox is supposed to be checked, check it
    target.forEach(function(val){
      if(cb.value === val){
        cb.checked = true;
      }
    });
    
    // Create and configure label
   var label= document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for", cb.id);  // Labels should target an element's id
   label.textContent = item; // No need to go through the trouble of making a text node
    
    // Append elements into the DOM
    label.appendChild(cb); 
   cbh.appendChild(label);
    
    // Confirming Output:
    console.log(label.outerHTML);
   });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

#data { padding:5px; width:100vw; }

.multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:50px;
}

.checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
      
label { display: inline-block; border: 1px grey solid; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `cb.checked = true` to check the checkbox when created.

```
if (target.indexOf(cap) != -1) {
    cb.checked = true;
}
```

Adding snippet:

```
function getCheckbox(value, label, checked) {
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  cb.value = value;
  cb.checked = checked;

  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.innerHTML = label;

  return [cb, label];
}

var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

var checked = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday'];

var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var container = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i=0, len=days.length; i < len; i++) {
  var dom = getCheckbox(i, days[i], checked.indexOf(days[i]) != -1);
  container.appendChild(dom[0]);
  container.appendChild(dom[1]);
}

cbh.appendChild(container);
```

Comment: You can update the snipet, so I will clearly see how should I do that and where. The objectiv is if I change the values in the array it will check an other checkbox

Comment: When you are creating dom inside a loop, it is better to use functions or closures so that the references don't create an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if one array contains a specific string with:
 [**Array.prototype.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control) <sup>ES6</sup> or
[**Array.prototype.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Also don't forget that `<label>` can wrap both your `input` and text-*label*

```js
var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes'),
dayNames  = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wendesday","Thirsday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"],
preselect = ["Tuesday", "Wendesday"];

for (var i in dayNames) {
  var day = dayNames[i];
  
  var label = document.createElement("label"),
      cb = document.createElement('input'),
      text = document.createTextNode(day);
  
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cb.name = day;
  cb.value = i;
  // PRESELECT MATCHING inputs
  // if(preselect.includes(day)) cb.checked = true; // or like:
  if(preselect.indexOf(day) > -1) cb.checked = true;
  
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well better solution was provided by @Scott Marcus but you can also try this,

```
 <!-- language: lang-css -->
    <style>
        * {
                        box-sizing: border-box;
                    }
                    #data {
                        padding:5px;
                        width:100vw;
                    }
                    .multiselect {
                        overflow: visible;
                        padding:0;
                        padding-left:1px;
                        border:none;
                        background-color:#eee;
                        width:100vw;
                        white-space: normal;
                        height:50px;
                    }
                    .checkboxes {
                        height:100px;
                        width:100px;
                        border:1px solid #000;
                        background-color:white;
                        margin-left:-1px;
                        display:inline-block;
                    }

                    label {
                        display: inline-block;
                        border: 1px grey solid;
                        padding:5px;
                    }
    </style>
    <!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form>
        <div id="data">
            <div class="multiselect">
                <div id="c_b">
                    <div id="checkboxes">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- end snippet -->


    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    <script>
    // table which generate checkboxes
        var array = new Array();
                    array[0]="Monday";
                    array[1]="Tuesday";
                    array[2]="Wendesday";
                    array[3]="Thirsday";
                    array[4]="Friday";
                    array[5]="Saturday";
                    array[6]="Sunday";

    // values to of checkboxes I want to auto-check
        var target = new Array();
                    target[0]="Tuesday";
                    target[1]="Wendesday";

                    var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
                    var val = '';
                    var cap = "";

                    var j = "";
                    for (var i in array) 
                    {
                        //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
                        j = i.toString();
                        val = j;
                        //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
                        var cb = document.createElement('input');
                        var label= document.createElement("label");
                      cap = array[i];
                      var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
                      cb.type = 'checkbox';

                     //added
                      target.forEach(function(a)
                      {
                        if(cap == a)
                        {
                            cbh.appendChild(cb).click();
                        }else
                        {
                             cbh.appendChild(cb);
                        }
                      });
                      //added


                      cb.name = cap;
                      cb.value = val;
                      label.appendChild(cb); 
                      label.appendChild(text);
                      cbh.appendChild(label);
                    }

    </script>
```